# Magento correct invocation of translation

Tags: magento

Which of these if functionally the correct way to invoke a helper in Magento:

```
Mage::helper('helper_class)->__('String to be translated);
```

v

```
$this->__('String to be translated);
```

Answer (score 1):

Both!

It really depends where are you invoking it and where is your translation is located.

Let's take a look at them. First this one:

```
$this->__('String to be translated);
```

If it is called inside of the helper class itself it will return a translation of the module this helper belongs to. Otherwise it will return core Magento translation.

```
Mage::helper('helper_class)->__('String to be translated);
```

In all other cases this code have to be used to get a translation of a specific module.

Comment: Good info, one minor detail - `$this` in block (& template) context will invoke using the block's `module_name` property, which is derived from the class name - see [`Mage_Core_Block_Abstract::__()`](https://github.com/benmarks/magento-mirror/blob/1.7.0.2/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Abstract.php#L1079) and [`::getModuleName()`](https://github.com/benmarks/magento-mirror/blob/1.7.0.2/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Abstract.php#L1063)